# R tcl issue on shared HPC cluster environment

Tags: r, tcl, r-caret, hpc

I've been having some issues getting R to run properly on the shared cluster at my institution , where i don't have root access.  Some things will work but it gets tricky when i need to install packages etc.  The current issue i'm trying to trouble shoot is the following error when trying to load the caret package:

```
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/cifs/hariri-long/Scripts/Tools/R/packages/rlang/libs/rlang.so':
  /cifs/hariri-long/Scripts/Tools/R/packages/rlang/libs/rlang.so: undefined symbol: R_removeVarFromFrame
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
Execution halted
```

I found [this page](http://asearchforsolutions.blogspot.com/2020/08/r-package-installation-error-in.html) suggesting i install rlang as follows:

```
> install.packages("rlang",type="source")
Installing package into ‘/cifs/hariri-long/Scripts/Tools/R/packages’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    /usr/share/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./library ./library ./tcl8.5.13/library ./tcl8.5.13/library
```

but i get the above tcl error.  since i've seen this in other threads:

```
> capabilities("tcltk")
tcltk
 TRUE
```

it looks like tcl on my system is 8.6, but i don't know how to tell R to look for that version.

```
$ whereis tcl
tcl: /usr/lib64/tcl8.6 /usr/include/tcl.h /usr/share/tcl8.6
$ which R
/opt/apps/rhel7/R-3.6.0/bin/R
```

Any ideas?  The OS is CentOS 8.  Thanks!

Comment: You've got an 8.5.13 compiled library (from somewhere, I don't know where), so it can't use an 8.6-specific supporting set of scripts; they have to match exactly (and 8.6 has quite a few features not in 8.5). You *might* be able to find things with `locate tcl` (produces lots of output) if the locatedb is set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deciding to try using a more recent R version (4.1.1) to solve this issue.  I was hesitant to do this at first because I have run into issues with availability / compatibility of packages I need in more recent R versions, but I wasn't getting anywhere troubleshooting this issue otherwise.  I figured that since TCL 8.6 is what was installed on the system, a newer version of R might be able to work with it, and seems i was right, since I got past the first error I was having when I switched.

I did get a new error regarding an issue loading the shared library Libtk8.6.so.  So I downloaded the .so file from [here](https://pkgs.org/download/libtk8.6.so) and unpacked it to my home directory using rpm2cpio (i don't have root access so i can't just use yum install etc).  After that i just had to re-install all my packages for the new R version and it worked!